# Container Engine/Kubernetes DNS to external

Tags: domain-name-system, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to let my containers on Google Container Engine point to a static IP outside of my Container Engine cluster (namely my db). Is it possible for me to prevent the use of an `/etc/hosts` file or a self managed bind server, and use Google Cloud DNS so I can configure a domain name inside of my containers? How would I go about doing this?

Comment: what do you mean point to a static ip ? you mean to connect from container to an external db ?

Comment: @silviud Yes that's right :-)

Comment: ok ... the container will use the regular resolver library ... so yes you can use google dns.

Comment: @silviud Cool do you have any resources on this? Haven't found anything telling me more about what you're describing yet..

Answer (score 1):

You can migrate to Cloud DNS using this guide. [1]

Compute Engine supports two types of external IP addresses [2]: Static external IP addresses and Ephemeral external IP addresses.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/dns/migrating 
[2] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vm-ip-addresses